# How to filter a table by clicking on images instead of using search?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

My table:

```
<div id="usertable">
    <div class="choicebox">
        <div id="choicebox">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        ALL
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        ADMIN
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        MEMBER
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="userbox">
        <table id="tablelist" >
            <tr>
                <div class="firstrow">
                    <div style="margin-left:20px;margin-top:12px;position:absolute;color:white">
                        User List
                    </div>
                </div>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td >
                    Name
                </td>
                <td>
                    User ID
                </td>
                <td>
                    Password
                </td>
                <td >
                    Organisation
                </td>
                <td>
                    Role
                </td>
                <td>
                    Status
                </td>
                <td>
                    Actions
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to achieve is when "Admin" is clicked on, it will only display the admins on the table, and vice versa. However, I have done some research and the best match I got for what i want to achieve is by using the search function, but it isn't what I am trying to achieve.

An example can be seen here: http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/tablefilter.shtml

Comment: without a search function, how do you want to achieve this. If possible create a demo using jsfiddle like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dmMCj/1/

Comment: Instead of typing to get the columns filtered, i want to click on either "All", "Member" or "Admin", and the column will filter out just as it would by doing the search method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### UPDATE : without thead and tbody / alternate row color

Check here, DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/hnJdX/2/

Note: I based on your table data, `7 columns` and texts, `Admin`, `Member`.

So, I check the colomn number 5 and text, and do the filter. If you have more columns and different text, please update the code accordingly.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alternateRowColor();

    $('#admin').on('click', function () {
        $('#tablelist tr').each(function () {
            $(this).show(0);
            if ($.trim($(this).children('td').eq(4).text()) != 'Admin') {
                $(this).not('.rowHeader').hide(0);
            }
        });
        alternateRowColor();
    });
    $('#member').on('click', function () {
        $('#tablelist tr').each(function () {
            $(this).show(0);
            if ($.trim($(this).children('td').eq(4).text()) != 'Member') {
                $(this).not('.rowHeader').hide(0);
            }
        });
        alternateRowColor();
    });
    $('#all').on('click', function () {
        $('#tablelist tr').each(function () {
            $(this).show(0);
        });
        alternateRowColor();
    });
});

function alternateRowColor() {
    var i = 0;
    $('#tablelist tr:visible').each(function () {
        if (i % 2 === 0) $(this).removeClass('odd').addClass('even');
        else $(this).removeClass('even').addClass('odd');
        i++;
    });
}
```

Comment: Just a quick question though, i am not using any tbody or thead in my table, so how do i make the function not read the 1st 2 rows?

Comment: check my update answer and demo again, give a class 'rowHeader' to these 2 rows. these 2 rows will not be hidden by now.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i got another question though, i have different colors for even and odd rows, so when i filter, the color of the rows stays the same, so how do i make it such that i get different colors for even and odd rows even when filter is done?

Comment: can you post your html/css/js that make different even/odd row color?

Comment: yes sure

`.userbox tr:nth-child(even){ background-color:#ebf6f8; }
.userbox tr:nth-child(odd)    { background-color:#c6d4d7; }`

Comment: check my update answer and demo again, i need to use 2 classes to achieve that. classes odd and even.

Comment: weird.. its not working on my code. Could it be because the rows are not premade? My rows are only added when i finish a form, could that be the problem?

Comment: you need to remove your old css, .userbox tr:nth-child(even){ background-color:#ebf6f8; } .userbox tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color:#c6d4d7; }

Comment: and add my new css  .even {
    background-color:#ebf6f8;
}
.odd {
    background-color:#c6d4d7;
}

Comment: The color does not appear on the row that is added unless i press the filter though. What could be the problem?

Comment: I call the function after document ready...$(document).ready(function () { alternateRowColor(); });... you still need to call after dom ready or after table created.

Comment: right now the order of the color is correct but after i press to filter, the order gets reversed..

Comment: because we are hiding some rows and show them again on filter, that is why we need to set alternate color (only for the visible rows), so this may change from current color depending on your filter, otherwise, you will get same color rows joining here and there.

Comment: I am not getting the same color rows already, its just the color pattern that's reversed when the filter function is activated.

Comment: humm, you want alternate color on filter, right? as your comment number 4. That s why i add color function. you want the same color rows, you can leave this function, and use your old css? I am not clear what you mean.

Comment: yes i want alternate color on fiter, however, when i filter, the color gets reversed between odd and even. So sorry about the confusion.

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/u2hTH/)

For some reason my submit button in jsfiddle isnt working..

Comment: on left top side of the screen, attach jquery lib file

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/u2hTH/1/

You'll have to scroll down to see the table though.

Answer (score 1):

I used JQuery here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Sample Project</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.choicebox table tr td a').click(function(e){
            var href = $(this).attr("href");
            if(href === "ALL"){
                $('#tablelist tbody tr').show();
                return false;
            }   
            $('#tablelist tbody tr').filter(function(index) {
                    var role = $(this).children()[4].innerHTML;
                    return role === href;
                }
            ).show();
            $('#tablelist tbody tr').filter(function(index) {
                    var role = $(this).children()[4].innerHTML;
                    return role !== href;
                }
            ).hide();

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="usertable">
        <div class="choicebox">
            <div id="choicebox">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="ALL">ALL</a></td>
                        <td><a href="ADMIN">ADMIN</a></td>
                        <td><a href="MEMBER">MEMBER</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="userbox">
            <table id="tablelist">
                <thead>
                     <tr>
                         <th>Name</th>
                         <th>User ID</th>
                         <th>Password</th>
                         <th>Organisation</th>
                         <th>Role</th>
                         <th>Status</th>
                         <th>Actions</th>
                     </tr>
                </thead>
               <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>nanfeng</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>123</td>
                    <td>org</td>
                    <td>MEMBER</td>
                    <td>OFF</td>
                    <td>DOING</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>beifeng</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>1234</td>
                    <td>org</td>
                    <td>ADMIN</td>
                    <td>OFF</td>
                    <td>DOING</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>dongfeng</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>1235</td>
                    <td>org</td>
                    <td>MEMBER</td>
                    <td>OFF</td>
                    <td>DOING</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hello, your code is very close to what i want, however it doesn't work when i tried to filter.

Comment: Doesn't work? Have you downloaded the jquery-2.0.2.js file to the folder? It works fine on my laptop.